# Allow nested struct to have an instance of containing class

Tags: c++, constructor, static, nested

I'm trying to get around c++'s lack of static constructors by having a struct declared within a Path class, and a static instance of that struct also in the Path class:

```
class Path
{
    struct StaticPathState
    {
        Path executablePath;
    }

    static StaticPathState s_staticPathState;
};
...
Path::StaticPathState Path::m_staticState;
```

However, I'm getting compile error:

> C2079: 'Path::StaticPathState::executablePath' uses undefined class
>   'Path'

Any way to get around this? Do I have to declare the struct outside of Path?

**What I ended up doing**

```
//.h
Path
{
  static Path s_executablePath;
  static Path initExecutablePath();
}

//.cpp
Path Path::initExecutablePath() {...}
Path Path::s_executablePath = Path::initExecutablePath();
```

Feel silly for not doing this in the first place. Spent too much time in c# land.

EDIT: [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx) is the feature I'm trying to replicate.

EDIT2: So this problem is that I need to run some code to initialize the executablePath member. In a language with static constructors, I'd put executablePath right into the Path class, as a static member, and initialize it in Path's static constructor. In c++, I'm not sure where to put this code.

Comment: What do you mean by a static constructor? What is the original problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: Well a static constructor makes no real sense, static members are parts of a a class that are accessable without any objects. And constructors are used to create objects. You might want to try the Singleton pattern

Comment: I want to control the initialization of static members. So, ideally, I'd have a static Path inside my Path class called executablePath. But there's some code that goes into initializing this path. Static constructors would let me do that at the start of the program. In c++, there are no static constructors, but and this is a workaround.

Comment: Wouldn't all public constructors be static in a sense? You don't actually have an instance at the time you call the constructor; that's what the constructor does.

Comment: Yes, but where should I initialize static members? See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forward declarations are your friend here:

```
class Path
{
    struct StaticPathState;

    static StaticPathState s_staticPathState;
};

struct Path::StaticPathState
{
    Path executablePath;
};

Path::StaticPathState Path::m_staticState;
```

But keep in mind this is pretty un-idiomatic C++ and will likely confuse any future maintainers. Don't try to write another language in C++. If you tell us the real problem you're trying to solve we can help solve that.

EDIT: Reading the comments one more time, it almost sounds like you're looking for static class members of class type that have their own constructors. Have you tried that?

Comment: Sure. I'm trying to have a static member of my Path class that represents the path of the current executable. I need to initialize this path somewhere. I can do something like check if it's initialized in a getter, and if not, initialize it and return it, but I was hoping there was a better way.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow your edit.. If you mean that I should create another class called ExecutablePath, then yes, that's a solution. But it's a little ugly, because the path of the executable is, its self, nothing but a Path..

Answer (score 0):

You can declare a static member of that class. In it's definition, you can call a static class method where you do your initialization. For example,

```
class Path
{
    struct StaticPathState
    {
        Path* executablePath;
    }

    static StaticPathState s_staticPathState;

    static StaticPathState MyStaticConstructor()
    {
       ///Do init work
       return pathState;//An appropriately created StaticPathState
    }
};
...
Path::StaticPathState Path::s_staticPathState = Path::MyStaticConstructor();
```

Comment: This was helpful, and pointed me to the (seemingly) best solution.